# Aggregate multiple columns based on specific date range with in a month

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to aggregate `Amounts` to be displayed by date range per month. To illustrate please take a look at the following table:

**Invoice_Payment**

```
Customer_id    Invoice_no    Invoice_date    Amount
---------------------------------------------------
10             10023         2016-07-08      60
10             10018         2016-08-04      90
11             10016         2016-07-01      110
11             10021         2016-07-05      120
12             10028         2016-07-11      10
12             10038         2016-07-31      5
```

As you'll notice, I want to group them based on `Customer_id` and display the dates from start to end. Furthermore, this has to be done for each month only.

Following query I have tried so far:

```
select Customer_id, (mindate + ' to ' + maxdate) Date_Range, Amount
from (
     select Customer_id, sum(Amount) Amount, min(Invoice_date) mindate, max(Invoice_date) maxdate  
     from Invoice_Payment
     group by Customer_id
     ) I ;
```

From above query I'm getting `Output` like:

```
Customer_id    Date_Range                    Amount
10             2016-07-08 to 2016-08-04      150
11             2016-07-01 to 2016-07-05      230
12             2016-07-11 to 2016-07-31      15
```

Please check this.. <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Working Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/520849)</kbd>

Let's say `Customer_id = 10` who has Invoice_date in `July,2016` and `August,2016`. I need to sum up all payments of that particular Customer for the month of July and August separately within specific date range. But I am getting sum of `Amount` of all `Invoice_date` from above endeavor.

Desired output :

```
Customer_id    Date_Range                    Amount
10             2016-07-08 to 2016-07-08      60
10             2016-08-04 to 2016-08-04      90
11             2016-07-01 to 2016-07-05      230
12             2016-07-11 to 2016-07-31      15
```

How could I get over this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Just add `YEAR` and `MONTH` to `GROUP BY`.

```
select Customer_id, (mindate + ' to ' + maxdate) Date_Range, Amount
from (
       select Customer_id, 
       sum(Amount) Amount, min(Invoice_date) mindate, max(Invoice_date) maxdate  
       from #Invoice_Payment
group by 
  Customer_id,
  YEAR(Invoice_date),
  MONTH(Invoice_date)
) I ;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about grouping by customer_id, month and year

```
select Customer_id, (mindate + ' to ' + maxdate) Date_Range, Amount
from (
       select Customer_id, 
       sum(Amount) Amount, min(Invoice_date) mindate, max(Invoice_date) maxdate  
       from #Invoice_Payment
       group by Customer_id,month(Invoice_date), year(Invoice_date)
) I
order by customer_id;
```